# Change div position on resize css

Tags: css, html

On the page there are two divs adjacent to each other. Now when I resize the browser, one of the div overlaps the other one. What I want is to move one of the div down (below the other div) when there isn't enough space to display both. Can it be achieved using css? How?

The body:

```
<div id="container">
   <h1 align="center">Title</h1>

   <div id="image1">
        <img src="back1.png" alt="a" />
   </div>

   <div id="image2">
       <img src="back2.png" alt="b" />
   </div>
</div>​
```

The CSS

```
#container {position: relative; height:800px; width: 720px; background: #f0f0f0;}        
#container #image1 {position: absolute;  top: 10%; left: 0;}​
#container #image2 {position: absolute;  top:0;  right:0;}​
```

Comment: Can you please post your CSS for these two divs? Otherwise it's hard to help.

Comment: Depends how you have them positioned. Maybe a `float: left;` or `display: inline-block;` would help?

Comment: You can post you code on something like [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: One second, making a new jsfiddle.

Comment: Sorry, wrong jsfiddle, check again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although you have not posted your code, I'm guessing that you style the div's by positioning them using relative or absolute positioning, which makes them overlap. I would instead use `display:inline-block;` to make adjacent divs in the manner you want.

[Click here](http://jsfiddle.net/WZKBm/) for an example of what I mean. Try resizing your browser to see that it works.

[Is this example](http://jsfiddle.net/u7cKk/1/) more of what you mean? I just used floats.

Comment: Works fine. Thanks. But can I use `display:inline-block;` if one of the div is class not id? (I mean one is `<div class="image1">` and other is `<div id="image2">`)

Comment: sure, just use .image1 { display:inline-block; }

Comment: This does not work if the divs have `position:absolute` property. I need to use  `position:absolute` property. So do i need some javascript to accomplish the task?

Comment: If you use position:absolute, then I can't think of a way to make the two boxes interact with one another short of javascript.